# Redux: useSelector returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I  have carefully gone through my code, nothing wrong with  store, reducer function, Provider, but useSelector  hook  returns undefined in the `App.js`. Why does it return undefined?

> redux.js

```
    import  {createStore} from 'redux'
    const  counterReducer = (state = {counter:0}, action)=>{
       if(action.type ==='increment'){
          return {counter:state.counter+1}
       }
       if(action.type ==='decrement'){
         return{counter : state.counter-1}
       }

   }
   const store =  createStore(counterReducer);

   export default store;
```

> index.js

```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import './index.css';
   import App from './App';
   import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
   import store from '../src/store/redux'
   import {Provider} from 'react-redux'


   ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store = {store}>
   <App />
   </Provider>,
     document.getElementById('root')
   );


   reportWebVitals();
```

> App.js

```
   import './App.css';
   import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

   function App() {
       const counter =  useSelector(state=>  state);
       console.log(counter)    //undefined

     return (
      <div></div>
     );
   }

  export default App;
```

Comment: Your reducer does not return anything by default. Its been a while since I've used Redux regularly, but I believe there are actions dispatched by redux itself on init. This means the action types will not match your conditions and there will be no return (undefined). Outside of your `if` blocks, return the previous state as a default - `return state`.

Comment: Your reducer needs to default `state` as noted by Brian.

Answer (score 1):

**redux.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
const counterReducer = (state = { counter: 0 }, action) => {
**// Updated previous if statement using switch statement**
  
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return { ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 };
    case 'decrement':
      return { ...state, counter: state.counter - 1 };
    default:
      return { counter: 0 }; // you need to define a default value;
  }
const store = createStore(counterReducer);

export default store;
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(counter);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'increment' })}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'decrement' })}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Look at this code, we always need a default value when creating reducer. Using **switch statement** for this case I think safe.
you can see this solution: [stackbllitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y58pxx?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: This really isn't a good solution. The default return of the reducer should be the **previous** state, not an initial state. When you have multiple reducers, *each* reducer gets called on every dispatch. This would mean `counterReducer` would get reset each time a completely separate reducer is meant to be updated.

Comment: Also I would suggest explaining your answer a little more than just *Look at this code, you will understand what's wrong*.

Comment: @BrianThompson  Previously, I have just changed some parts from his code so that it works. Didn't care about good or bad.  Now I have updated the answer the way I use it. Thanks! for your suggestion.